# WiFi - Does not connect because of different MAC's

Tags: 10.10, wireless, network-manager

In my university I have one Wi-Fi Network. If I need to access the Internet I access it with PEAP-authentication. Now the issue - all WiFi-Spots have the same name  (SSID: WLAN1) and Ubuntu sometimes refuses to connect.
What I saw is, that in syslog wpa_(dontknowanymore) says trying to connect with (MAC1) and the WiFi is associated with another MAC.
How can I fix this, so I can force my Ubuntu to reassociate?
Regards,

Answer (score 1):

you could try:

```
sudo iwlist
```

to bring up a list of wifi points with their respective AP MAC addresses

then find the one with the best signal quality, and manually configure what network to connect to using:

```
sudo iwconfig wlan0 essid essidnamehere
sudo iwconfig wlan0 ap MACaddresshere
```

and to finish off,:

```
sudo dhclient wlan0
```

I had the same issue before, and doing the above seemed to help me stay connected when I found a new spot to work. The issue got fixed for me though through one of the recent updates on natty.